# Batch import 100 tif images into QGIS

Tags: qgis-2

I want to import 100 tif images into QGIS. For each tif I have to click 'OK'. Is it possible to batch import all 100 without clicking ok every time?

Comment: What the message says before you press OK?

Comment: What method are you currently using to bring in the TIFs?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what message you are getting it might be the coordinate reference that is asked for. If you want to set it to a standard you can go to options-crs and set the wanted system under "crs for new layers".

Way more convenient use of many raster files is to use a raster mosaic. It can be easily created via raster-other- virtual raster catalog. It is way faster to work with this.